# Resize Images CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

**Imagine websites like 9Gag**. You upload an image and they display it always with the same width and only the height changes.

How can I achive this? I cant even resize my images hardcoded.

CSS:

```
.post img{
height: 200px;
width: 300px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="post">
  <img src="img/bf1.jpg">
</div>
```

The image stays the same size.

Answer (score 2):

You should change CSS style to:

```
.post img{
  height: auto;
  width: 300px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<div class="post">
  <img height="200px" width="300px" src="img/bf1.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!